# Best Fit packages - VBA request

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I produce items in batches of 15, 20, 26, 40.

```
    - If I need to fit 80 items in these batches,
 guess the best fit would be to use 2 of 40 (batches) or 4 of 20 batches..
```

Is there is a way to get this in a function or formula to get the best fit please dynamically so that I would know the best fit please....

[image: This the excel columns I have]

Comment: What is the measure for "best fit" and what are the constraints?

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply - There are no constrains (like in size etc., nothing).. just need to best fit so that it uses least amount of batch - in other words, if I need to fit 45 items.. I can use 40 batch and one 15 batch.. 

or two 20 batch and one 15 batch..

Comment: if you need 45 items, use 20 + 26, not 20+20+15 nor 40+15...

Comment: Yea.. sorry my bad..

Comment: You can use the Solver Add-In to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: This works only if we have a perfect divisor.. if we have 47 for example.. it is not working unfortunately

Comment: @Shyam you probably wanted to comment on Error 1004 answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207171/discussion-between-shyam-and-vincent-g).

Comment: Is this thread stil active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this code, please.
The batches values will be in the range "B1:E1". Only batches values (15, 20, 26, 40). If the string "Batch " must exist, it can be added by cell formatting ("Batch "###).
It does not return all possible variants. It tries to return the best match in terms of minimum number of batches. It probably can be improved, but not needing it, I was too lazy to do that also that...

On top of your module code put:

```
Option Explicit
Private boolOff As Boolean
```

And after that:

```
Sub testBatchOptimization()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrB As Variant, chkb As Double

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  arrB = sh.Range("B1:E1").Value
  chkb = sh.Range("B2").Value
  MsgBox recursiveBatch(arrB, chkb, 1)
End Sub
Function recursiveBatch(arrB As Variant, chkb As Double, levelX As Long) As String
    Dim nrB As Long, nrBOld As Long, i As Long, Rez As Long, boolF As Boolean
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrB, 2)
        Select Case levelX
            Case 1
                If chkb = arrB(1, i) Then
                    Rez = arrB(1, i): nrB = 1: boolF = True: Exit For
                ElseIf chkb Mod arrB(1, i) = 0 Then 'fix division
                    If nrBOld = 0 Then
                        nrB = chkb / arrB(1, i): _
                               Rez = arrB(1, i): boolF = True
                    Else
                        If nrBOld >= chkb / arrB(1, i) Then _
                              nrB = chkb / arrB(1, i): _
                              Rez = arrB(1, i): boolF = True
                    End If
                    nrBOld = chkb / arrB(1, i)
                End If
            Case 2
                If i = UBound(arrB, 2) And chkb > arrB(1, UBound(arrB, 2)) + _
                    arrB(1, UBound(arrB, 2) - 1) Then recursiveBatch = recursiveBatch(arrB, chkb, 3)
                     If boolOff Then boolOff = False: Exit Function
                If arrB(1, i) >= chkb Then
                    recursiveBatch = "one batch of " & arrB(1, i)
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf arrB(1, i) < chkb And arrB(1, i + 1) And i < UBound(arrB, 2) >= chkb Then
                    recursiveBatch = "one batch of " & arrB(1, i + 1)
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf arrB(1, i) + arrB(1, i + 1) >= chkb And chkb > arrB(1, UBound(arrB, 2)) Then
                    If i = 3 And arrB(1, i + 1) + arrB(1, 1) >= chkb Then
                        recursiveBatch = "1 batch of " & arrB(1, 1) & " plus 1 batch of " & arrB(1, i + 1)
                        Exit Function
                    ElseIf i = 3 And arrB(1, i + 1) + arrB(1, 2) >= chkb Then
                        recursiveBatch = "1 batch of " & arrB(1, 2) & " plus 1 batch of " & arrB(1, i + 1)
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                        recursiveBatch = "1 batch of " & arrB(1, i) & " plus 1 batch of " & arrB(1, i + 1)
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            Case 3
                If chkb < arrB(1, 1) + arrB(1, 2) + arrB(1, 3) + arrB(1, 3) Then
                    If arrB(1, 4) + arrB(1, 3) + arrB(1, i) >= chkb Then
                        recursiveBatch = "1 batch of " & arrB(1, i) & " plus 1 batch of " & arrB(1, 3) & _
                                        " plus 1 batch of " & arrB(1, 4)
                        boolOff = True: Exit Function
                    End If
                Else
                   recursiveBatch = interpretCase(Rez, nrB, chkb)
                    boolOff = True: Exit Function
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
    If boolF Then
        If Rez = 20 Or Rez = 26 Then
            If nrB > 2 Then
                recursiveBatch = interpretCase(Rez, nrB, chkb)
                boolOff = True: Exit Function
            Else
                recursiveBatch = nrB & " batches of " & Rez
            End If
            Exit Function
        ElseIf Rez = 15 Then
            If nrB > 3 Then
                recursiveBatch = interpretCase(Rez, nrB, chkb)
                boolOff = True: Exit Function
            Else
                recursiveBatch = nrB & " batches of " & Rez
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If

    Else
        recursiveBatch = recursiveBatch(arrB, chkb, 2)
    End If
End Function
Private Function interpretCase(Rez As Long, nrB As Long, ByVal chkb As Long) As String
    Dim nr40 As Long, nr26 As Long, nr20 As Long, nr15 As Long, rest As Long
    nr40 = Int(chkb / 40)
    rest = chkb - (nr40 * 40)
    If rest <= 15 Then
        interpretCase = nr40 & IIf(nr40 = 1, " batch ", " batches ") & "of 40 and 1 batch of 15"
    ElseIf rest <= 20 Then
        interpretCase = nr40 & IIf(nr40 = 1, " batch ", " batches ") & "of 40 and 1 batch of 20"
    ElseIf rest <= 26 Then
        interpretCase = nr40 & IIf(nr40 = 1, " batch ", " batches ") & "of 40 and 1 batch of 26"
    Else
        interpretCase = nr40 + 1 & " batches of 40"
    End If
End Function
```

I tested it for a limited number of times and values. I did not observed any mistake, but it may have problems being not accurately tested as it should...

I think it is easy to be understood. I tried some comments but it started to become bushy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

**Sheet structure:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngBatches As Range, cell As Range
    Dim No_Items As Long
    Dim strResults As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngBatches = .Range("B1:E1")
        No_Items = .Range("B2").Value

        For Each cell In rngBatches

            If No_Items / cell = Int(No_Items / cell) Then
                If strResults = "" Then
                    strResults = "Option(s):" & vbNewLine & No_Items / cell & " batches of " & cell & " items."
                Else
                    strResults = strResults & vbNewLine & No_Items / cell & " batches of " & cell & " items."
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

        MsgBox strResults

    End With

End Sub
```